# Azure Devops REST API SendMail

Tags: azure, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to send mail after the successful stage on my release definition.
Following the docs
OAuth box is checked in my stage
Project Collection Service Account is added to Build Administrators and Release Administrators.

But the response from REST API is "Azure DevOps Login Page"
Here is my script:

```
$OrganizationName = "myorg"
$ProjectName = "myproj"
$sendmailto = "example@mail.com"
$mysubject = "Test Mail Subjcet"
$mailbody = "Mail body to test it works with azure rest api" 
$PAT="MYPAT"
$Token = "$(System.AccessToken)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$Token"))

$HeaderMail = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $encodedCreds"
}


##send mail
$urimail = "https://${OrganizationName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/${ProjectName}/_apis/Release/sendmail/$($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)?api-version=3.2-preview.1"
$requestBody =
@"
{
"senderType":1,
"to":{"tfsIds":[$sendmailto]},
"body":"${mailbody}",
"subject":"${mysubject}"
}
"@
Try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urimail -Body $requestBody -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $HeaderMail
}
Catch {
$_.Exception
}
```

**Tested with:**
Tried with 3.2 version and 7.1

PAT Token and authorization to Basic return 400 with Bearer return 401.

Switch $(System.AccessToken) to $($env:System_AccessToken) trygin to convert to base64 and without.

What I'm missing?

Response from
[ConsoleLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWMA2.png)

Comment: Hope you are not using a proper URI. Could you recheck it again POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1-preview.1

Comment: Тhis API needs parameters for WorkItems etc. I don't need to attach work items or run queries I just want to send after release stage simple mail

Comment: Reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-send-emails-with-send-email-azure-devops-re/1561423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the $requestBody. The request body requires valid Azure DevOps users referenced by their `tfsIds`.

Below PS script works for me, if your are running it in pipeline, then please use the `$(System.AccessToken)` instead of `$PAT`.

Running locally and authenticate with `PAT`:

```
$OrganizationName = "organization"
$ProjectName = "Project"
$sendmailto = "xxx@microsoft.com"
$mysubject = "Test Mail Subjcet"
$PAT="xxx"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT"))

$HeaderMail = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $encodedCreds"
}

#Get the tfsid

$userentitlementurl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/${OrganizationName}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userentitlementurl -Method Get -Headers $HeaderMail

#Filter by sendmailto
$tfsid = ($response.value| where {$_.user.mailAddress -eq $sendmailto}).id

Write-Host $tfsid

##send mail
$urimail = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${OrganizationName}/${ProjectName}/_apis/Release/sendmail/168?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$requestBody =
@"
{
    "senderType": 1,
    "to": {
        "tfsIds": [
            "$tfsid"
        ],
        "emailAddresses": []
    },
    "subject": "$mysubject",
    "sections": [
        5,
        0,
        1,
        2,
        4
    ]
}
"@
Try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urimail -Body $requestBody -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $HeaderMail
}
Catch {
$_.Exception
}
```

[image]

Running in release pipeline and authenticate with `$(System.AccessToken)`: (Please note that, because this script is being run during the release, the summary email will show the environment as `IN PROGRESS` even if it is run as the last step in the Release.)

```
$OrganizationName = "organization"
$ProjectName = "project"
$sendmailto = "xxx@microsoft.com"
$mysubject = "Test Mail Subjcet"

$HeaderMail = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
 
#Get the tfsid

$userentitlementurl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/${OrganizationName}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userentitlementurl -Method Get -Headers $HeaderMail

#Filter by sendmailto
$tfsid = ($response.value| where {$_.user.mailAddress -eq $sendmailto}).id

Write-Host $tfsid

##send mail
$urimail = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/Release/sendmail/$($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$requestBody =
@"
{
    "senderType": 1,
    "to": {
        "tfsIds": [
            "$tfsid"
        ],
        "emailAddresses": []
    },
    "subject": "$mysubject",
    "sections": [
        5,
        0,
        1,
        2,
        4
    ]
}
"@
Try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urimail -Body $requestBody -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $HeaderMail
}
Catch {
$_.Exception
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but i am unable to get any response (blank response). No email received.

Comment: This works only for Release pipelines or it can work for build pipelines as well?