# Azure pipelines, how to create release notes

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, cicd

In azure pipelines, once I fix some bug/task, I tag the number with hashtag #, so once my code merges to the master, those backlogs become "done" status automatically.

My goal is, once we deploy this to any stage on release pipeline, (lets say UAT stage) I want those completed backlogs to be sent to user/customer to test automatically.

Is there a custom task or sth to manage this?

Note: i do not want all completed backlog list to sent, only the completed ones between two deploys, like a differential.
So that they will know what to test.

Maybe we can call it, automatically created release notes by the way :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the completed work items have been associated with a commit every time. Then you can try extension [Generate Release Notes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SpeedTechSolutions.GenerateReleaseNotes). This Extension is used to Generate Release Notes based on difference in Commits and Work Items between two BuildId's. You can also find other similar extensions from [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops)

After that, you can add a PowerShell task at the end of state and write script to call [Send Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) REST API to send the completed work item list to the specific users.

Reference:

- [Is it possible to link a work item to a release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655380/is-it-possible-to-link-a-work-item-to-a-release/52658229#52658229)
- [Azure Devops REST API SendMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601908/azure-devops-rest-api-sendmail/71611809#71611809)